# TeX program option in TeX Live Utility

Tags: texlive

For the option of TeX programs in the preference of TeX Live Utility, I have read that the path /Library/TeX/texbin should be applied. However, when this path is used in TeX Live Utility, I got the following message: 
The tlmgr tool does not exist at /Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr.  Please set the correct location in preferences or install TeX Live.

The only thing I can do now is to set the preference of TeX Live Utility with the path of the local folder (x86-64) to normally update the packages.

So where went wrong in this case?

Comment: You should probably rephrase your question, it is not really clear (1) what you are trying to do, (2) what is going wrong.

Comment: OK, I have rephrased my question. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Which version of mac osx are you using?

Comment: Also exactly which mactex is this?

Comment: OSX version: High Sierra 10.13   MacTex 2017

Answer (score 1):

In you install using a recent version of MacTeX, `/Library/TeX/texbin` is the correctly location. If you install using the UNIX installer, you will have to set the path manually. I believe the documentation is clear about this, but feel free to let me know how it can be improved. From the **Help** menu, choose **TeX Live Utility Help** and click the **Preferences** link for detailed instructions.

Comment: (I believe you just earned the [edit questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Adam. However, the program cannot use /Library/TeX/texbin. What about if I choose the path in local...texlive..2017..bin. The program can work properly with the above path through the local folder.

Comment: @Johannes you can use a path in `/usr/local/texlive/2017…`, but it will be incorrect for future installs. I would try reinstalling MacTeX, as it sounds like some of its links are broken.

Comment: Thanks Adam for the suggestions. Could you explain to me what do you mean ''but it will be incorrect for future installs''? Is this something to do with updating packages? Or it refers to the future new version of MacTeX? Thank you!

Comment: If you install a new version of MacTeX (say, 2018), TeX Live Utility will be pointing to the old one from 2017. Using `/Library/TeX/texbin` insulates you from those changes, and lets you use the version-switching feature in TeX Live Utility to switch between TL versions.